# Manual bootstrap in Polymer

Tags: polymer, lifecycle

Is there an imperative way to bootstrap Polymer, in the style of [Angular bootstrap](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap)?

The [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html) give details about individual elements lifecycle, but nothing about the framework itself.

I'm looking for a way to reconcile Polymer with requirejs and I need to force a single point of entry into my app. If I can bootstrap Polymer from within the [requirejs data-main](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#data-main), I'm good.

related material:
 - [Working with Polymer and requirejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26026942/working-with-polymer-and-requirejs)
 - [Require.js to load all resources for an app, including Polymer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841189/require-js-to-load-all-resources-for-an-app-including-polymer)
 - [Polymer + requirejs: Attributes on were data bound prior to Polymer upgrading the element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509501/polymer-requirejs-attributes-on-were-data-bound-prior-to-polymer-upgrading-th)
 - [requirejs+polymer thread on google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/polymer-dev/bdSyt-QXFE8)
 - [polymer+requirejs gist](https://gist.github.com/tantaman/7222599)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out a simple way to manually trigger my app to bootstrap (at least it works for single page app), here's how you can do it too:

- Don't import any of your `custom-element.html` from the `index.html` or any other page directly imported from the index. Your `polymer-ready` event should fire straight away but none of your custom elements will be loaded. This may require additional steps on your part [to avoid FOUC](http://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/polymer.html#polymer-ready) and what not.
- When you want to bootstrap your app, use the [polymer.import](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/helpers.html#using-dynamic-html-imports) helper function to kick things off. If you have a hierarchy of elements importing each other, you only need to manually import the top-level elements, the others will be imported through html imports. You can repeat this with different elements at different times if you want to import parts of your app dynamically.